# Bash script to run commands in other directories regardless of level

Tags: bash

I have a directory structure that looks something like this

```
|- .ci
|- node_project
|- scripts
|- terraform
```

In the scripts directory I want to add wrapper scripts for things like `build.sh`, `verify.sh` and `deploy.sh`, however if we consider `build.sh` the content could be something like

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd ../node_project
npm run build
```

That will work as long as you are in the `scripts` directory.

How would I create a script that would also work is it's called from the project root directory as `scripts/build.sh` or even from outside the project as `<some random path>/scripts/build.sh`?

Comment: See [BashFAQ #28: How do I determine the location of my script? I want to read some config files from the same place.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` has the current script's name. Get the script's directory and go from there.

```
cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")"

cd ../node_project
npm run build
```

Be careful. If the user passed in any relative paths they won't resolve correctly any more.